# @name and @@keyword not working with rule annotations

Tags: annotations, keyword, tatsu

I'm trying to use @@keyword and @name in my grammar but tatsu seems to ignore it if rules tagged @name are annotated.

Am I missing something?

To reproduce the behaviour, I provide the following example:

This one works:

```
import tatsu

GRAMMAR = '''
@@grammar::TestGrammar
@@keyword :: if var
@@whitespace :: /[\t ]+/

    start =
        var identifier ";" { var identifier ";" }* $
        ;

    if = "if";

    var = "var";

    @name
    identifier = 
            /[a-z]+/;
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    import json
    from tatsu import parse
    from tatsu.util import asjson

    ast = parse(GRAMMAR, 'var xyz; var if;')
    pprint.pprint(ast, indent=2, width=20)
```

As expected, tatsu will report

```
tatsu.exceptions.FailedParse: (1:16) "if" is a reserved word :
var xyz; var if;
               ^
```

If I annotate the identifier rule by

```
    @name
    identifier = 
        id:
            /[a-z]+/;
```

the same python program will output

```
( 'var',
  {'id': 'xyz'},
  ';',
  [ [ 'var',
      {'id': 'if'},
      ';']])
```

Comment: Please tell which version of TatSu you are using?

Comment: I'm using TatSu 5.5.0

Comment: You should be using [TatSu 5.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/tatsu/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should not define:

```
@name
identifier = 
    id:
       /[a-z]+/;
```

TatSu will match the ast resulting from the rule against the names `@@keyword`, and the output of the above rule will always be `{'id': 'something'}`, which will not match any keyword.

Perhaps what you want is something like:

```
identifier = id:_identifier;

@name
_identifier = /[a-z]+/;
```

Comment: Shou should mark the answer as accepted :-)